# Serializing a Control in Silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize a control to XAML in Silverlight 5.
Basically, I am using the following code:

```
var ignore = new XmlAttributes();
attrs.XmlIgnore = true;

var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(FrameworkElement), "Resources", ignore);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(control.GetType(), overrides);
```

However, when I try to actually serialize the control, I get an exception about the Resources property implementing IDictionary, although I specifically marked it for ignoring.
What am I doing wrong? Any other way to do this?

Comment: My hunch is that the Resources property is not going to be your last problem, though I might be wrong. Can you explain what your scenario is for wanting to serialize FrameworkElements?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the quick reply! I am trying to build a ContentTemplate control that includes a control passed as parameter. I want to build a XAML string that I can later on parse into a ContentTemplate.

Comment: Hmmm, tricky. I assume you want a _clone_ of the control? I would've suggested using `XamlWriter` and `XamlReader`, but I don't think `XamlWriter` is present in Silverlight, although attempts have been made: [google Silverlight XamlWriter](https://www.google.nl/#newwindow=1&q=Silverlight+XamlWriter). [Bing actually yields better results](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Silverlight+XamlWriter)

Comment: Yes, I want a clone. What I am really looking for is a way to create ControlTemplates with content programmatically. Can't find a way to add content to a ControlTemplate other than parsing from XAML.

Comment: Well this doesn't bode well for your quest: "...In Silverlight, control templating is entirely done by defining XAML. The API surface of FrameworkTemplate and ControlTemplate is not intended for and is not capable of defining templates for a control by creating a ControlTemplate in code..." (from the remarks section in [ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.95).aspx))

Comment: Yeah... but it should be possible... anyway, thanks!